# Solution to a linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x_1' = -ωx_2$

$x_2' = ωx_1$

Show that $y(t)=(\cos(ωt), \sin(ωt))$ is a solution and then find another solution z(t) such that $(y(t), z(t))$ are linearly independent and check the independence?

I don't fully understand how to show this is a solution.  (Why is sin and cos a solution?) and also how would i check the linear independence?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: differentiate your first equation again wrt $"t"$ you get 2nd order differential equation whose solution is of the form $y(t)$

Comment: $y(t)$ is the pair $(x_1(t), x_2(t))$, and the 'prime' notation indicates differentiation w.r.t. $t$.  Thinking of $y(t)$ as a vector with two components, in order for $y$ and $z$ to be independent, neither can be a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: i dont understand how to think of it as a vector! I have just started learning this hence could someone please explain fully?

Comment: I would advise you to see your teacher and ask whether a working knowledge of linear algebra is a prerequisite for the course and, if it is, drop the course and take linear algebra first.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Thanks for your rude and pointless input. Will be ignored :)

Comment: camilla, I wish you the best of luck --- but I've seen too many students fail courses they should never have enrolled in, because they weren't ready for them. I get the feeling that this course expects people to know quite a bit about linear algebra, and the questions you are asking make me wonder whether you have the necessary background to succeed in the course. It can't hurt to see the teacher to have a little chat about it. The course is not going to get any easier.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

If you wrote out the system as a matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\omega \\ \omega & 0\end{bmatrix}$, you would find the eigenvalues $\pm i \omega$, but they are not asking you to do this (it was meant to explain - but skip it).

So, if you use the solution they provided, we have:

$y(t)= (x_1(t), x_2(t)) = (\cos(ωt), \sin(ωt))$

$x_1(t) = \cos (\omega t)$, and $x_2(t) = \sin (\omega t)$, show they satisfy each of those equations in the system (just compare both sides of the equation by taking derivatives).

Example: $x_1(t) = \cos(ωt)$, so, $x'_1(t) = -\omega \sin (\omega t) = -\omega x_2(t)$. Compare that to your first equation. See it?

You can do $x_2(t)$.

How do you show linear independence?

Comment: Ahhhh sorry i really dont understand using matrices and vectors for this, i know how to use them when not applied to this but they have just been introduced for this course now and i dont know how to apply them to this! could you explain the vector this a bit and then i will probably understand! I think that is what i am stuck on!

Comment: See my update for more details.

Comment: thanks very much i can see that now yes! will have to do some reading on this though as not used matices like this before!! Not surehow to show linear dependance with ODE's my notes dont seem to say much to do with linear dependance and searching the web is hard as im getting lots of irrelevant things!

Comment: also, unsure what it means when it says find another new solution such that the previous solution and the new solution are linearly independant, how do i find a linearly dependant solution and then check it?

Comment: How do you prove linear independence for vectors? Can you guess another solution from the one given that meets linear independence?

Comment: yeah i know how to prove it for simple vectors but this has confused me - maybe its just a bit late.. never mind im sure ill figure it out.

Comment: Sammy also gave a nice hint too on the vector - look at it fresh in the morn - regards